# Xamarin.Forms.Pages.ListDataPage not loading Data from AzureEasyTableSource

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to use the new *Xamarin.Forms.Pages.ListDataPage* control that is currently in Preview.

I have followed the instructions on the getting started page [Getting Started with DataPages](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/datapages/getting-started/) to set up an *AzureEasyTableSource*.
The app compiles and runs, but `this.DataSource.Data.Count` always returns 0, on both iOS and Android.

Bellow is the Views XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:ListDataPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sparrow" 
    xmlns:azure="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Pages.Azure;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Pages.Azure" 
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Pages;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Pages" 
    x:Class="Sparrow.NewsPage" StyleClass="Event" Title="News" BindingContext="This">

<p:ListDataPage.DataSource>
    <azure:AzureDataSource>
        <azure:AzureDataSource.Source>
            <azure:AzureEasyTableSource TableName="NewsItem" 
                                        Uri="https://<<AppName>>.azurewebsites.net"/>
            </azure:AzureDataSource.Source>
        </azure:AzureDataSource>
     </p:ListDataPage.DataSource>


    <p:ListDataPage.DefaultItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <p:ListItemControl
               Title="{ Binding Value[headline] }"
                Detail="{ Binding Value[newsBody] }"
                DataSource="{ Binding Value }"
                HeightRequest="30"
            />

        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</p:ListDataPage.DefaultItemTemplate>
</p:ListDataPage>
```

A Wireshark capture and the App Service streaming logs show that the server is receiving and responding to the requests, but the application fails to process the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like perhaps your data bindings are a problem here as they should correspond with the values that are coming in and need special syntax. Here is an example of mine taken from my OCR sample: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/app-ocr-functions:

```
 <p:CardView
          Margin="10"
            Text="Total Amount from OCR:"
            Detail="{p:DataSourceBinding Total}"
            ImageSource="{p:DataSourceBinding Url}"
            DataSource="{Binding Value}"
            HeightRequest="250"/>
        </ViewCell>
```

You must use the p:DataSourceBinding to the name of it.